# Split Strings with Tabs but Some Info is Missing

Tags: c, string, delimiter, strtok

I am reading information in from a text file that follows this pattern: Id, JobTitle, BasePay, OvertimePay, Benefit, Status. Each part is separated by a tab character. An example of one line is below:

```
81387   Architectural Associate 114146.55   0   0   FT
```

However, some lines have base pay missing, and there is instead two tab characters so it would look something like:

```
81392   Deputy Chief        0   149934.11   FT
```

When I use strtok with "\t" as the delimiter, it automatically skips over the two tab characters here and goes straight to 0 which is the OvertimePay. Here is the code that I used ("current" is a struct that I'm using to store each piece of info, and ptr has already been defined as a char array):

```
ptr = strtok(salaryLine, delim);    // This gives us ID, which we already have. Skip this
ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
strcpy(current.title, ptr);
ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
current.basePay = strtod(ptr, &empty);   // This is a problem because it takes OvertimePay instead if BasePay is missing
ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
current.overtimePay = strtod(ptr, &empty);
ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
current.benefit = strtod(ptr, &empty);
ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
strtok(ptr, "\n");  // Remove newline character
strcpy(current.status, ptr);
```

Is there a way that I could flag strings like that. Specifically, how can I find a string that does not have BasePay in the file? I've tried searching the string for two tab characters next to each other and that doesn't work.

```
char* temp = strstr(ptr, "\t\t");
            
if (ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("It's null");
}
            
else
{
    printf("It found it");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use strtok. Use other ways like `strchr` instead to find the next tab. For further help show the actual code for "*I've tried searching the string for two tab characters next to each other*".

Comment: As you have found, `strtok` will not work for your use case - it will skip multiple consecutive instances of the delimiters. Please show the other way you tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using multi delimiter makes no difference. strtok(ptr, "\t") is the same with strtok(ptr, "\t\t").

In that case I prefer "p2 = strchr(p1, '\t')" loop with a memcpy(s, p1, p2-p1) inside.

BTW, strtok isn't reentrant. use (BTW: reentrant has nothing to do with multi-threading. strtok breaks already with nested loops. One can use strtok_r but it's not as portable.)